# Monitoring packet loss simulated with tc

Tags: networking, ip, monitoring, ping, tc

I found an interesting article that describes [how to simulate network issues](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/network-failures-simulation) (like lost packets) on a linux server.

On an Ubuntu test VM, I checked which interface is used for internet connectivity, and it's called `ens33`.

Then I added a rule using `tc` to introduce packet loss:

```
$ sudo tc qdisc add dev ens33 root netem loss 30% 50%
```

And then I let `ping` run for a while, the result is as expected, some packets are lost:

```
$ ping www.google.com
...
97 packets transmitted, 84 received, 13% packet loss
```

While `ping` was running, I thought I could also monitor the ongoing packet loss using `ip -s link show ens33`, but it shows 0 dropped packets both for `RX` and `TX`.

What I'm trying to do is to monitor packet loss in realtime, while `ping` is running.

Comment: This is purely a guess, but since what `tc` actually does is "traffic control", it's possible that this loss is not shown by `ip -s link` since it is not real packet loss, as the packets are "lost" before hitting the interface.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, that could really be that the packets get lost before going to the interface. My goal of the whole exercise is to see how the common tools used to debug network issues like `ip` etc. behave when packets get lost, errors happen etc. I thought maybe `tc` would be a good way to simulate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tc` also accepts a [`-s`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/tc.8#s) parameter, with the same meaning: statistics.

Example as root applied on a veth link toward an LXC container with address 10.0.3.128:

```
# echo; tc qdisc del dev vethlzYQu1 root 2>/dev/null; \
  ip neigh flush all; \
  tc qdisc add dev vethlzYQu1 root netem loss 30% 50%; \
  tc -s qdisc show dev vethlzYQu1 root; \
  ping -q -c 10 10.0.3.128; \
  tc -s qdisc show dev vethlzYQu1 root 

qdisc netem 8010: root refcnt 5 limit 1000 loss 30% 50%
 Sent 0 bytes 0 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
PING 10.0.3.128 (10.0.3.128) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 10.0.3.128 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 8 received, 20% packet loss, time 9193ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.030/125.218/1001.185/331.084 ms
qdisc netem 8010: root refcnt 5 limit 1000 loss 30% 50%
 Sent 826 bytes 9 pkt (dropped 3, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
```

Here 9+3=12 packets should have been sent, 2 of the dropped packets were from the ping, and the other was probably an ARP request which was retried.

If you need to parse `tc`'s output in shell, better use its JSON output along `jq`. Eg:

```
# tc -s -json qdisc show dev vethlzYQu1 root | jq '.[].drops'
3
```